# Need help building indexes for web based search tool on Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a SQL Server 2016 SP2 database. One of the tables containing call detail records is the largest with around 123 million rows and approx 25 columns.

Let's call this `CDRTable`.  We have a web based search tool that always uses columns 1, 2 and 3 in search queries. However, columns 4, 5, 6 and/or 7 may or may not be used used in the selection criteria.

I've built non-clustered indexes for columns 1-4 + one of the variable columns that perform well. Other all inclusive index attempts don't get called. The database is bloated with so many indexes.

Is there a way to build a single index for such variability?

Should I be looking at columnstore indexing?

Comment: When you said "I've built non-clustered indexes for columns 1-4...", do you mean you have a separate index for each of column 1, column 2, column 3, and column 4? Or one index containing all of those columns?

Comment: You should have only one index for the first 3 colums, and include the other colums that are used in the selection. For the described scenario.

Comment: Also use [sp_blitzIndex](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit)

Comment: Yes, one index for columns 1-3.  I've added the include for the remainder.  Execution plan suggest including fields to index that are in the where statement. Separate indexes for those other columns?   If the select includes the same set of additional columns(not searchable) should those be added to the include of the index?